# PowerManager in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android

I would like to know if there is a possibility to implement the "PowerManager" method in a hybrid application using javascript.
If possible, the indication of material for study, and implementation

Thank you

Comment: English please.

Comment: Please use https://pt.stackoverflow.com for questions written in Portuguese. (Google Translate: Por favor, use https://pt.stackoverflow.com para perguntas escritas em português.)

Comment: ok...obrigado...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a UWP javascript app you can check if your device is plugged in using PowerManager:

```
// check if plugged in
var pss = Windows.System.Power.PowerManager.powerSupplyStatus;
if (pss === 0) {  // unplugged
           document.getElementById("a2").innerHTML = "unplugged";
} else {                
           document.getElementById("a2").innerHTML = "plugged in";
}
```

In a Cordova Apache Cross Platform app, install cordova-plugin-battery-status. Then listen for "batterystatus".  The JavaScript is:

```
window.addEventListener("batterystatus", onBatteryStatus, false);
function onBatteryStatus(status) {
    var bs = status.level + "%" + " Plugged in: " + status.isPlugged;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can run and use local web server or socket which will take POWER-action via json-request.
Not native, but very simple and lot of ready REST examples.